# XPath for WebDriver

Tags: internet-explorer, webdriver, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I am using Windows 10 build Insider Preview 10532. I see status of XPath on page support Edge WebDriver is **partial** ([Edge WebDriver Status](https://dev.modern.ie/platform/status/webdriver/details/)).

Which case runs fail with XPath?

Answer (score 0):

XPath is supported full on Window 10 Build Insider Preview 10547.

More detail at http://dev.modern.ie/platform/status/webdriver/details/